# How to regenerate/rebuild Firefox add-ons web extensions documentation website to host locally

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

#### What I'm trying to do

I'm trying to rebuild/regenerate **[MDN Web Docs](https://github.com/mdn/content#welcome-to-mdn-web-docs)** website locally on my machine. It's currently hosted on github with numerous folders and subfolders but I'm interested specifically in building only the `add-ons web extensions subfolder`.

So my desired path, on github, would be:

> `content/files/en-us/mozilla/add-ons/webextensions/`

Basically I'm trying to regenerate this portion of the documentation and all of its subfolders locally, using data on github:

> `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions`

#### Problem I've encounter trying to rebuild/regenerate the documentation website

1. First problem, I'm behind a very restrictive/complicated firewall :( and to rebuild the docs I would need to install all sorts of dependencies/packages/libraries from `npm`. So when I try to do so, I get all sorts of nasty errors saying that basically I can't install this dependency and that dependency from `npm`.
2. Second problem, let's say, I somehow manage to pass through that nasty firewall, the **[MDN Web Docs](https://github.com/mdn/content#welcome-to-mdn-web-docs)** contains thousands upon thousands of documentation pages in `markdown` format about everything related to web, but I'm only interested in the add-ons sections of it! I'm wondering how I'm supposed to regenerate only that specific part of it!

#### Things I've tried to get around these problems

I've tried to research around the web but I couldn't find any tutorial (I mean NONE/ZERO) nor any solid documentation on this. On **[MDN Web Docs  - Build the site](https://github.com/mdn/content#build-the-site)**, it says, go ahead and download the repo and use `npm` to install it locally which is a very generically vague and confusing guidance, at least to me.

I also tried to manually install a `markdown to html convertor` in order to regenerate the extensions subfolder and the `markdown` files, but it's a huge recursive folder and there are many subfolders and pages and I don't think it's feasible for me, at this point, to go down that path!

Has anyone done this before? Is anyone willing to help me or point me in the right direction?